# FileUpload error Size en file[0]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

Tengo un control de asp para subir archivos.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuAttachmentsSoporte" CssClass="required"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>    
<asp:Button ID="btnAttachmentsSoporte" runat="server" Text="Adjuntar" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnAttachmentsSoporte_Click" disabled />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HFUploadMaxFileSize" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMensajeError" style="display:none;" CssClass="ms-formvalidation">El archivo seleccionado excede del tamaño máximo permitido.</asp:Label>
```

Mediante una funcion de javascript controlo el tamaño del archivo, y si es mayor de lo deseado se lo indico al usuario y no desbloqueo el boton de adjuntar.

```
function ValidateMaxSize(fileId) {

    var file = document.getElementById(fileId);        
    var fileSize = file.files[0].size / 1024;

    var lblError = file.parentElement.children[4];
    var btn = file.parentElement.children[1];

    lblError.style.display = 'none';        

    var maxFileSize = document.getElementById("HFUploadMaxFileSize").value;

    if (fileSize > maxFileSize) {

        lblError.style.display = 'block';
        btn.disabled = true;

        return false;
    } 
    btn.disabled = false;
    return true;

}
```

El problema radica en que si borro ese archivo y le doy a guardar, me da error! y la cosa es que aunque resetee el input o ponga su valor a 0 `file[0]` sigue teniendo valor...

Haciendo lo mismo con un archivo pequeño no me sucede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma para limpiar un `input` de tipo `file` es reemplazándolo por un clon de si mismo:

```
function ValidateMaxSize(fileId) {

    var file = document.getElementById(fileId);        
    var clon = file.cloneNode();

    var fileSize = file.files[0].size / 1024;

    var lblError = file.parentElement.children[4];
    var btn = file.parentElement.children[1];

    lblError.style.display = 'none';        

    var maxFileSize = document.getElementById("HFUploadMaxFileSize").value;

    if (fileSize > maxFileSize) {
        file.parentNode.replaceChild(clon, file);

        lblError.style.display = 'block';
        btn.disabled = true;

        return false;
    } 
    btn.disabled = false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'replaceWith'

Comment: @GDP oh lo siento me he confundido, replaceWith() es de jQuery y no de javascript nativo, te he editado la respuesta con un método nativo!

Comment: Ya decia yo jajaja gracias camilo! lo del clon me ha funcionado. Lo otro llevaba probandolo un tiempo y nada.

Comment: @GDP me alegra que te funcionara, edite la respuesta con la forma que realmente te ha servido, saludos !